# can I sort a list based on another list in C#

Tags: c#, list

say I have a list (List_1) of ints:
{3, 1, 2}

then I sort that list to be: {1, 2, 3}

can i sort another list of strings (List_2): {"eg1", "eg2", "eg3"}

can i sort List_2 based on the sorting of List_1, for example:
list_1 goes from {3, 1, 2} to {1, 2, 3}
then list_2 goes from {"eg1", "eg2", "eg3"} to {"eg2", "eg3", "eg1"}

is this possible in c#?

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem. If two lists are related you should use a different type, for example a `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: You can do this if you use an array rather than a list, using [`Array.Sort(Array keys, Array? items)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that contains both items, and then sort that list:

```
class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Text {get;set;}
}

var unsorted = new List<Item>
{
    new Item{Id = 3, Text = "eg3"},
    new Item{Id = 1, Text = "eg1"},
    new Item{Id = 2, Text = "eg2"},
}

var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x=>x.Id);
```

Further examples of OrderBy here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby

Comment: sorry for the late response, but this is very helpful and something I didn't think of myself, again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code to show how you can group those values, sort them together, and then separate them again:

```
var list1 = new[] { 3, 1, 2};
var list2 = new[] { "eg1", "eg2", "eg3" };
var combined = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b}).ToList();
var sorted = combined.OrderBy(e => e.a).ToList();
var list2Sorted = sorted.Select(e => e.b).ToList(); // eg2, eg3, eg1
```

However, I'd question why your data isn't already represented with those values connected to one another. Neil's answer is correct: if the data in your lists are related that's a sign that you should have a single collection of objects with both properties related to one another.